# Odoo 12 : Changes are not visible when updating existing module

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to update some static text in template name `ajax_login_template.xml` inside `website_ajax_login module`.

I have restored an existing dump file without any errors.

The issue is that I can't see the changes after updating the app in `developer mood`.

But the changes get visible as expected when I use a new database instead of the dumped version and fresh install `website_ajax_login_module`. To simplify my question and what I did as follows:

```
First Attempt

Step 1 -> Restore dump file into a database.

Step 2 -> Update template.xml file

Step 3 -> Activate Developer Mood and upgrade the App. i.e. `website_ajax_login` 

Result ===> Changes Not Visible.

Also if I click on top menu item "Customize -> HTML/CSS editor". No windows open at the right side of the screen.

Second Attempt 

Step 1:  Go to web database manager view
Step 2: Create a database (not restore list in the first attempt)

Step 3: Install website_ajax_login app

Result ====> Changes Visible I made in the template.xml file.

if I click on top menu item "Customize -> HTML/CSS editor". The window opens on the right side of the screen without any problem.
```

Is there some cache etc involved in this error. When using the dumped version of my database, I see the error logs as follows.

```
2020-05-18 10:58:57,541 127210 INFO archixpress odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /home/shahzeb/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/archixpress/bd/bdbf3e6ea7597eb4b2305c7e8e083430facaa1b2 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1039, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 38054
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 976, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1041, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.attachment(38054,).datas', None)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shahzeb/Projects/Wiztech/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 113, in _file_read
    r = base64.b64encode(open(full_path,'rb').read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/shahzeb/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/archixpress/bd/bdbf3e6ea7597eb4b2305c7e8e083430facaa1b2'
2020-05-18 10:58:57,561 127210 INFO archixpress werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 10:58:57] "GET /web/image/38054/160x160/ HTTP/1.1" 304 - 5 0.009 0.041
2020-05-18 10:58:57,575 127210 INFO archixpress odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /home/shahzeb/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/archixpress/26/269f4b4e91c4bc57d9d535ad3c8fcd907d975031 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1039, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 38056
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 976, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1041, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.attachment(38056,).datas', None)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shahzeb/Projects/Wiztech/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 113, in _file_read
    r = base64.b64encode(open(full_path,'rb').read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/shahzeb/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/archixpress/26/269f4b4e91c4bc57d9d535ad3c8fcd907d975031'
2020-05-18 10:58:57,578 127210 INFO archixpress werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 10:58:57] "GET /web/image/38056/160x160/ HTTP/1.1" 304 - 5 0.009 0.041
2020-05-18 10:58:58,001 127210 INFO archixpress werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 10:58:58] "POST /web/dataset/call HTTP/1.1" 200 - 3 0.051 0.032
2020-05-18 10:58:58,079 127210 INFO archixpress werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2020 10:58:58] "POST /website/translations HTTP/1.1" 200 - 12 0.116 0.142
2020-05-18 10:58:58,095 127210 INFO archixpress odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /home/shahzeb/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/archixpress/cd/cd5a21b5fca4934040122813fb0d1214003f6ca7 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1039, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 38113
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 976, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1041, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.attachment(38113,).datas', None)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

As a test, I Created a new module and every thing works fine with new module.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem because someone had altered the view using debug tools inside Odoo.  The solution can be found on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650510